# PHP Getting Image Extension For Validation

Tags: php

I am calling a get_file_extension() function to return the type of file: i.e jpg, gif etc:

```
function get_file_extension( $file )  {
    if( empty( $file ) ) {
     return false;
    } else {

    // if goes well then good to go
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //var_dump($ext);

    // return file extension
    return $ext;

    }
}
```

when I do a var_dump($ext) the file type is getting captured however the $ext is not getting returned from the function!

The function call:

```
 $filename = stripslashes( $_FILES['file']['name'] );
 $ext = get_file_extension( $filename );
 $ext = strtolower( $ext );

 var_dump($ext);
```

If I do a var_dump() for $ext, it is holding the extension correctly but when I try to validate the extention with:

```
if(( $ext != "jpg" ) && ( $ext != "jpeg" ) && ( $ext != "png" ) && ( $ext != "gif" ) ) {
  $error = 'Unknown Image extension.';
  return false;
}
```

The error message does not get displayed on the screen.

When I check the apache error_log I get the following error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference
```

.... which relates to this line in my get_file_extension function:

```
$ext = substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1);
```

I get a similar error if I use PATHINFO:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why are you using string operations on a filename? [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) does ALL of that for you already, and far more reliably.

Comment: PHP has methods to get file extension. have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php

Comment: When I use pathinfo, I get the following error: Only variables should be passed by reference for the line ( $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: You should answer your own question instead of adding the answer as an update

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out.  Answer added.

Answer (score 0):

PATHINFO_EXTENSION is much more up to date BUT the reason the error message was not getting displayed was because $error = ' '; was not defined in the global scope. You could also have just echoed the error message.